VBA Formatted Text But Remove Hyperlinks first
I have a VBA macro that will format the text the way I like it. However, whenever there are hyperlinks, emails or mentions (i.e., @Tom), the Regex validations will include strings that are not within the proper format.
My solution to this would be to first have any hyperlinks in the drafted email be removed prior to running my formatting macro, that way it formats without any hyperlinks.
Below is the code I written for the formatting but I am having trouble figuring out where I can include the removal of hyperlinks:
Sub ValidateAndFormatText()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olInspector As Object
    Dim olMailItem As Object
    Dim olRange As Object
    Dim re As Object
    Dim signatureStart As Long
    Dim signatureEnd As Long
    Dim textToValidate As String
    Dim match As Object
    
    ' Initialize Outlook objects
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olInspector = olApp.ActiveInspector
    Set olMailItem = olInspector.currentItem
    Set olRange = olMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range
    
    ' Define your signature text
    Dim signatureText As String
    signatureText = "Best,"
    
    ' Find the position of the signature
    signatureStart = InStr(1, olRange.Text, signatureText, vbTextCompare)
    signatureEnd = signatureStart + Len(signatureText)
    
    ' Extract the text above the signature
    textToValidate = Left(olRange.Text, signatureStart - 1)
    
    ' Initialize the regular expression
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    
    ' Validate and format monetary values
    re.Pattern = "\$[0-9]{1,3}(([\.?,?][0-9]{1,3}){1,})?\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

    ' Validate and format monetary values
    re.Pattern = "\$[0-9]{1,3}[KM]\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match
    
    ' Validate and format time values (e.g., 10:30 AM)
    re.Pattern = "\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\s?[AaPp](\.?)[Mm]\1)?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

    ' Validate any digits with or without percentage signs
    re.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,2})?\%"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' Number Long
    re.Pattern = "\b(?:two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)(-day)?\b(\s\([0-9]{1,}\))?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match


' Weekday
    re.Pattern = "\b(Happy)? (Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' Random Codes etc
    re.Pattern = "\b(([0-9]{1,}) psi|([0-9]{1,}) PSI|NFPA (25)|([0-9]{1,}) GPM|([0-9]{1,}) mph|([0-9]{1,}) MPH)\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' Civil Code
    re.Pattern = "\bCivil Code \d{4}(\(?[a-zA-Z]\)?)?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' Palos Verdes Bay Club Building and Units
    re.Pattern = "\b[0-9]{1,2}-([A-H]|[0-9]{3})\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' Number (00)
    re.Pattern = "\b(?:two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)(\s\(\d+\))?\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

' 28-day comment period
    re.Pattern = "\b28-day\s(comment period)?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

    ' Validate and format long date values (e.g., Sunday, May 9, 2024)
    re.Pattern = "\b((?:Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday),\s)?(?:January|February|March|April|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (\d{1,2}(,)?) \d{4}\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

        ' Validate and format long date values (e.g., 02/14/2024)
    re.Pattern = "(?:January|February|March|April|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(\s\d{1,4})?(,?\s\d{4})?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = False
    
    ' Validate and format long date values (e.g., Sunday, May 9, 2024)
    re.Pattern = "\b((?:Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday),\s)?(?:January|February|March|April|May\b|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (\d{1,2}(,)?) \d{4}\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

        ' Validate and format long date values (e.g., 02/14/2024)
    re.Pattern = "(?:January|February|March|April|May\b|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)(\s\d{1,4})?(,?\s\d{4})?"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True

   ' [#XN] number
    re.Pattern = "\[#XN[0-9]{7}\]"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match
    
    ' Validate and format date values (e.g., 02/14/2024)
    re.Pattern = "\b[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}([/-][0-9]{2,4})?\b"
    For Each match In re.Execute(textToValidate)
        olRange.Start = match.FirstIndex
        olRange.End = match.FirstIndex + match.Length
        olRange.Font.Bold = True
        olRange.Font.Color = RGB(8, 30, 54) ' Navy blue
    Next match
End Sub 


I afraid that the workaround you use currently is the most convenient way.

@Christy - the code I made works but I don't know the syntax or what I should do specifically for hyperlinks. Are you able to assist?
